# Biostrings: How to write XStringSet object fasta file in R

Tags: r, fasta

I used ?writeXStringSet to get an idea of how to write my xstring set as a fasta file.

we have some examples there like this:

```
## Write FASTA files:
out23a <- tempfile()
writeXStringSet(x23, out23a)
out23b <- tempfile()
writeXStringSet(x23, out23b, compress=TRUE)
```

My question is how to write the file into my desktop instead of writing as tempfile().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consult the documentation by running `?writeXStringSet`. You write the file to your desktop (or whatever path you want) by setting

```
out23a <- "~/Desktop/out23a.fasta"
```

and

```
out23b <- "~/Desktop/out23b.fasta"
```

instead of using `tempFile()`.